# How to Click on a Button using content-desc

Tags: c#, android, testing, appium

i'm new to testing in C# using Appium. I was able to set everything up and to run test.
I used UiAutomatorViewer to get access to some Buttons, now i need to Click on a Button, but i just got the Cont-desc. **Which FindElement(ByAndroidUIAutomator."") is linked to the cont-desc**? I tried everything but i always get an error. I already tried to Click on this Button using TouchAction or mouse.Click();Nothing worked...
Any Help would be nice.

Thanks in advance:)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The easy way to access to an element using content-desc is with

```
driver.findElementByName("Login").click();
```

IMPORTANT: be careful with spaces, I had problems finding the element because the text in content-desc had a space at the end of the text...

Answer (score 1):

Find the webelement by XPATH and then click on it as below:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//android.widget.Button[@content-desc='Login']")).Click();
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked out for me.

driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("UiSelector().description(\"Login\")").click();

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiSelector.html#childSelector(com.android.uiautomator.core.UiSelector)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`driver.FindElement(By.Name('Login')).Click();`

This is the way to access content-description. It is basically the name of the view.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2023 and I'm using Appium's Python bindings but for an ANDROID app, I'm able to get an element using its **content-desc** using **accessibility id** even though accessibility id is generally understood to only work for iOS.  Not sure if this will work for C# or other bindings

```
--> e=d.find_element(by='accessibility id', value='Search')
--> e.get_attribute('content-desc')
'Search'
--> e.get_attribute('resource-id')
'com.my.app:id/search_button'
--> e.get_attribute('name')
''
```